# xdotool script to perform mouse moves and clicks

Tags: bash, scripts, xdotool

I'm new to xdotool and I have a bash script to do some automated clicks for me, but the clicks don't seem to be occurring. I think it's because I'm not selecting the window, though I'm not very confident about that assessment.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in $(seq 1760 45 1895)
do
    for y in $(seq 760 45 985)
    do
        xdotool mousemove x y click 3
        sleep 0.1
        xdotool mousemove x y+20 click 1
        sleep 0.1

    done
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most importantly, a variable is called using `$`, and `y+20` doesn't work that way. However, you don't even need to calculate that, just use `mousemove_relative 0 20`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in {1760..1895..45}; do
  for y in {760..985..45}; do
    xdotool mousemove --sync $x $y click 3 sleep 0.1 \
    mousemove_relative --sync 0 20 click 1 sleep 0.1
  done
done
```

Additional changes I made:

- substitute the `seq` subshell using [Brace Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace)
- use `xdotool`'s builtin `sleep` function → only call it once
- call `mousemove` with the `--sync` option to let it wait until the mouse is actually moved