# How to click+hold+move with xdotool?

Tags: automation, xdotool

I've digged on StackExchange and on the YouTube but everywhere only how to `clicks and moves`. My question is how to click+hold e.g. some desktop icon and move it to different location with xdotool or highlight area with mouse arrow on the desktop which also require click+hold+move?
Here is a bit related question [xdotool script to perform mouse moves and clicks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953486/xdotool-script-to-perform-mouse-moves-and-clicks) but still different.
As well I've tried to find in manual here [xdotool - command-line X11 automation tool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/xdotool.1.html)

There is written:
`xdotool lets you programmatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows`

But I cannot find how. Can anyone help please?

According suggestions I tried following:

So here is following:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in 'seq 1 200'
do
  xdotool mousemove 1519 599 mousedown
  sleep 2
  xdotool  mousemove 1519 750 mousedown
  sleep 2
  xdotool mousemove 1600 750 mouseup
  sleep 2
done
```

and it is just move the mouse but doesn't highlighting area on the desktop which is should be is left button of the muse is pushed down.

Answer (score 3):

"Dragging" should work by first have `xdotool` press the mouse button with the `mousedown` command. Then issue the `mousemove` commands, and issue `mouseup` when done dragging.